# confused with berkshelf, chef and vagrant

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf

I've took a look on [BerkShelf documentation](https://docs.chef.io/berkshelf.html). I've been able to figure out it stands for managing cookbook dependencies. So, guess I'd like to build a machine with java. I've first generated my custom cookbook:

```
chef generate cookbook custom-java
```

My `Berksfile` is:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
metadata

cookbook 'java'
```

and my `metadata.rb` is:

```
name 'custom-java'
...
version '0.1.0'
```

After that, I've simply run `berks install`, so all dependencies have been resolved and located under `~\.berkshelf\cookbooks`.

Nevertheless, I don't quite figure out how to use my `custom-java` into my vagrant configuration. What do I need to do in order for vagrant to provistion this cookbook into my machines?

My vagrant structure is:

```
VagrantFile
├───chef
│   ├───cookbooks
│   │   ├───(((1)))  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
│   ├───roles
│   │   ├───java-dev-workstation.rb
```

`Vagrantfile` content is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.roles_path = "chef/roles"
    chef.cookbooks_path = "chef/cookbooks"
    chef.add_role "java-dev-workstation"
  end
end
```

And `java-dev-workstation.rb`:

```
name "java-dev-workstation"

default_attributes( 
  # Because it's Oracle, we need to agree to the terms and conditions.
  :custom-java => {  >>>>>>>>>   (((2)))
    :install_flavor => 'oracle',
    :jdk_version => '8',
    :accept_license_agreement => true,
    :oracle => { "accept_oracle_download_terms" => true } 
  }

)

run_list(
  "recipe[java]"
)
```

I'm using Chef 12.18.31.

1. On `(((1)))`: Do I need to "import" my `custom-java` cookbook, how? Where is it located?
2. On `(((2)))`: How should I configure `java`?

**EDIT**
I've set `chef.cookbooks_path`:

```
config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.roles_path = "chef/roles"
    chef.cookbooks_path = 'D:\projects\living\vagrant\production\berk\custom-java'
    chef.add_role "java-dev-workstation"
end
```

**EDIT2**

Nevertheless, `custom-java` dependencies are not resolved now:

```
================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: yum

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* custom-java

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux
```

My `metadata.rb` content is:

```
name 'berk'
...
version '0.1.0'

supports 'centos'

depends 'yum'
```

Currently, all dependencies are located in `~/.berkshelf/cookbooks`. It seems `shef-solo` is not looking for in it...

Comment: You can add `custom-java` to the run_list of `java-dev-workstation.rb` role.

Comment: How is vagrant going to resolve `custom-java` cookbook if I've not upload it in anywhere?

Comment: you are provisioning with `chef_solo` and provide `cookbooks_path` - it's enough.

Comment: I'm getting a not resolved cookbook. I've edited the post.

Comment: You don't need `\custom-java` part in the `chef.cookbooks_path`. Should be like `D:\projects\living\vagrant\production\berk`

Comment: I'm getting a cookbook dependency is not resolved now. It seems like that even though I've set that it look at on `D:\projects\living\vagrant\production\berk`, it's not able to look for dependencies located on `~/berkshelf/cookbooks`. I've edited the post.

Comment: `cookbooks_path` can be an array. Add there all the folders where your cookbooks are.

Comment: It keeps failing. I've set `chef.cookbooks_path = ['D:\projects\living\vagrant\production\berk', 'C:\Users\Beep\.berkshelf\cookbooks']`.

Answer (score 0):

You did take it backward for a *wrapper cookbook* pattern, your `custom_java` should depends on `java` and change its default behavior (overriding node attributes).

Your custom-java metadata.rb should contain a line like this, what is in the berksfile will never be interpreted by the chef-client run, it's an outside dependency resolver to create coherent bundles.

```
depends 'java', '~> 1.47'
```

And the default.rb a line

```
include_recipe 'java'
```

Then your `Berksfile` can omit the cookbook line (unless you're pulling a version elsewhere than the source at top)

Next your role should use `custom-java` as recipe and not `java`, then the chef-client run (the vagrant part before edit sounds ok and should pull both cookbooks) will compute attributes from the `java` coobooks, overwrite those defined in `custom-java` and you should end up with the desired behavior.

Alternatively, you can just set the runlist to `custom-java` and avoid the role altogether, that will works.

I highly recommend you to go through all the tutorials on https://learn.chef.io to get a better overview.